# Problem with UnicodeDecodeError in massive file

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, utf-8, large-files

I'm trying to read a 7GB csv zipped file using pandas, reading by chunks.

The file is UTF-8-BOM, so I'm using that encoding in the read_csv.
After 2 hours of reading, it always raises this error:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec cant decode byte 0xd0 in position 7478: invalid continuation byte
```

I've tried a lot of different encodings. It only goes through latin_1 but with some weird characters in the beginning that I assume is the BOM of the file.

When I open the file using 'Large Text Viewer' and I go to the end of the file, the program crashes. This does not happen with other massive files. I suspect that there is something wrong in the end of the file that is causing this error, since its always being raised after 2 hours.

I also tried to convert the csv to parquet, but it raises the same error.

I'm having problems visualizing the file cause its massive, so I don't know what next steps to make.

Comment: You know the position of the error in the file. So open the file in `rb` mode and seek to a position a little before that, and then read a smallish chunk that includes the problem byte (e.g. read bytes 7450 to 7500). Once you've got that, edit your question and show the chunk of ***raw bytes*** (don't try to decode it). It *might* be possible examine the bytes of that chunk and fix the error. However, there might be more errors after that position, which might indicate that the encoding is not, in fact, utf-8 (e.g. a utf-8-bom might have been prepended to a file with a different encoding).

Comment: PS: what sort of data is in the file? Is it likely to contain lots of non-ascii characters?

Comment: Its international european data, so i think it can contains non-ascii characters. Will try to do what you explained. Also, is possible that the position that the error is giving me is the position inside the chunk that was currently being read?

Comment: PPS: if possible, please also show the bytes of the first three lines of the file (including the BOM).

Comment: Unfortunately, if the position is in the current chunk, you'd need to count chunks and then multiply by the chunk-size to calculate the file position. So maybe just read lines in `rb` mode and decode each line until you find the error that way. Having a full line would probably be more useful anyway.

Comment: Thank you @ekhumoro I did what you said and I've found a lot of records with bad encoding. A lot of '?', cirilic characters and �.